# How do I get better gems?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I found this gem, it's cool and all, but it just doesn't have that oomph I'm looking for.

How can I upgrade it? Or failing that, what can I do with it that will help me to get a more powerful gem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine 3 gems at the Jeweler to get 1 gem of the next higher quality level. Once you get to higher level gems, additional ingredients will also be required, such as Pages of Jewelcrafting or Tomes of Secrets. There are 14 tiers of gems in total.

See the [list of Jeweler recipes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/) for more information on the specifics.

Answer (score 4):

While the above answers about combining are true, the prices on the AH make low level gems cheaper to purchase outright via gold than by combining them. Aka, if it cost 500g to make a gem out of cheaper gems, that gem usually sells for far less than 500g.

Comment: I've been doing that. I picked up a square gem for under 10k. That's cheaper than combining chipped gems, plus you don't have to find them. And a Square Ruby does +100 damage for me!

Comment: +1. Don't use the gem artisan without checking the auction-house first... I threw away lots of gold by combining gems before I noticed that. Now I don't even bother picking up the low quality gems. It's just not worth it.